# Probability of winning coin game

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, game-theory

You will play a coin game against an opponent. A biased coin will be continually flipped
where there is a 2/3 chance of Heads and a 1/3 chance of Tails.

If Heads is flipped then you receive \$1 from your opponent. If Tails is flipped then you pay
\$1 to your opponent.

You start with \$10 and your opponent starts with \$20. You keep playing until one of you is
bankrupt (= has \$0 left); they will be declared the loser, the other will be declared the
winner.

What is the probability, that you win?

> This seems similar to Gambler's Ruin except the coin is biased. Would this still balance out to 50%? Is there a way to solve this without using stochastic equations?

Comment: It is still a [Gambler's Ruin question, just with an unfair coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Unfair_coin_flipping).  It seems your probability of winning is more then $99.9\%$

Comment: Your probability of winning would be $\frac47 \approx 57\%$ even if you started with $1$ coin and your opponent $2$ coins

Comment: Thanks for the help. Intuitively how does the 99.9% make sense? I'm trying to rap my head around it. Does having a higher probability of winning mean that much more than having more chances? I suppose if you have a higher chance of winning, you will win more in the long run. And with more coins in the game, the game will inherently be longer. Is this correct intuition?

Comment: That is how I would see it intuitively. More bets involved increases the effect of the biased coin